# Where is the nginx ./configure for compiling a dynamic module?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

i want to compiling a dynamic module. But i don't find the configure? I use nginx with Ubuntu 18.04.
Where is the ./configure?

Thank you.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/converting/#compiling-dynamic

Comment: Did you download nginx's source?

Comment: Ah sorry, that was it... I thought that "apt-get install nginx" was sufficient.